# Heart Rate monitor using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to build heart rate monitor where the user can put his finger over the camera with flash on and the heart rate is displayed to him.

As of now I am capturing the video from my phone and then processing it using OpenCV in my laptop.

The steps I am following is:

- capture the video
- find the average red plane value for each frame
- filter the data so that unwanted peaks are removed
- calculate the peaks and then display heart rate

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2

  #connecting with the captured video file taken from mobile
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture('heart_rate.mp4')

  #getting the number of frames 
  no_of_frames = int(cap.get(7))

  #assigning an initial zero red value for every frame
  red_plane = np.zeros(no_of_frames)

  #time_list is used for storing occurence time of each frame in the video  
  time_list=[]
  t=0

  #camera frame per second is 30 and so each frame acccurs after 1/30th second
  difference = 1/30
  for i in range(no_of_frames):

      #reading the frame
      ret,frame = cap.read()
      length,width,channels = frame.shape

      #calculating average red value in the frame
      red_plane[i] = np.sum(frame[:,:,2])/(length*width)
      time_list.append(t)
      t = t+ difference


  cap.release()
  ```

I am not able to apply a low pass filter to smooth my data and also how can I find the peaks using OpenCV.
Any help would be great.

Comment: please also google for 'fft' and 'eulerian magnification'

Comment: Why do you want a low pass filter? Its good to pass a gaussian filter to blur the frames to remove details and noise. For the peaks, I would treat this after all frames are analysed

Comment: @tales_padua I want a low pass filter to smooth the graph so unwanted peaks can be removed and only desired peaks are left . Actually I am calculating a single red value that describe an individual frame and thus i am finding the red value for each frame in my video and then I want to find the peaks

Comment: And also classical ICA method: https://www.osapublishing.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eosapublishing%2Eorg%2FDirectPDFAccess%2F7837271D-E125-1CC6-EE97D78E3759B369_199381%2Foe-18-10-10762%2Epdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D199381%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org=

Comment: To smooth the image I would use a gaussian filter. You can take a look here on how to use it, along with some other usefull useful methods: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

I make the Video at 30FPS, sum every frame r-channel and store the averaged  sum to a list.  Then I plot the list in matplotlib as follow.

[image]

We can easily find about eight peaks from frame `90` to frame `300`. In other word, there are `7 periods in 200 frames( taken in 200/30 s)`, so the heart rate is `7 / (200/30) = 21/20 => 63/60`. This to say, my heart rate was `63`.

Maybe, the `Fourier Analysis` will help. But, unfortunately, I still have no idea how to analysis this curve in programs ...

(Because I forget the  `Signals & System` by `AlanV.Oppenh` )

ORZ ...

---

A heart beat finger gif.

[image]